# How to approach web-scraping in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am new to python just started on python web-scraping. I have to scrape data from this [realtor site](https://example.com)

I need to scrape all the details op **read-state agents** according to their **real-state agency**;
For this **on the web-browser I have to follow the following instructions**

1. Go to [this site](https://www.xample.com/find-agent)
2. click on agency offices button, enter 4000 pin in search box and then submit.
3. then we get list of the **agencies**.
4. go to our team tab and then we get agents their.
5. then we have to go to each **agents page** and record their information.

**Can anyone tell me how to approach this.** Whats the best way to make this type of scrapers.

Do i have to use **selenium** for the interaction with the pages.

I have worked on **request**, **BeautifulSoup** and simple form submit using **mechanize**

Comment: In their terms of service:
"""In accessing or using our platform you agree that you will not:

  (a)  use any automated device, software, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, or index our platform or any content on our website; """

I think that you should not state that you intend to break the terms of service of a website publicly.

If you want to talk about scraping other websites with search functions (where scraping does not break their ToS) you may want to look into requests with sessions.

Comment: ok my bad. I was just giving an example. Can you  explain a bit about your answer request with session. My main issue is how to handle the interactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend on a searching site that you either use Selenium or Requests with sessions, the advantage of Selenium it it will probably work however it will be slow. For Selenium you should just use the Selenium IDE (Firefox add on) to record what you do then get the HTML from the webpage and use beautifulsoup to parse the data.

If you want to scrape the data quickly and without using much resources I usually use Requests with Sessions. To scrape a website like this you should open up a modern web browser (Firefox, Chrome) and use the network tools for that browser (usually located in developer tools or via right click inspect element). Once you are recording the network you can interact with the webpage to see the connections made to the server. In an example search they may use suggestions e.g

```
https://suggest.example.com.au/smart-suggest?query=4000&n=7&regions=false
```

The response then will probably be a JSON of the suggested results. Once you select a suggestion you can just submit a request with that search parameters e.g

```
https://www.example.com.au/find-agent/agents/petrie-terrace-qld-4000
```

The URLs for the agents will the be in that HTML page, you just then need to separately send a request to each page to get the information using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: the second part is using APIs of the site. this one is absolutely better then using selenium but sometime we dont able to find the request details. I was asking question for that problem where we need to interact with UI before getting the data e.g. AJAX data load.

Comment: Yeah it is probably best to use the API directly through Requests. You may need to use sessions too as they may be tracking via a sessions cookies, this means you probably have to visit a webpage to get a session cookie before using the API.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna give Node and Jquery a try. I used to use Python all the time, but it gets messy and hard to maintain after a while.

Using node, you can turn the page HTML into a DOM object and then scrape all the data very easily using Jquery. I have done this for imdb here:  “Using JQuery & NodeJS to scrape the web” @asimmittal https://medium.com/@asimmittal/using-jquery-nodejs-to-scrape-the-web-9bb5d439413b

You can modify this to scrape yelp

Comment: i am trying to learn the python after trying it on node. I find it node scrapping much more complex . may be i don't know much